# How to rename a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, file-io

According to the documentation the way to go about it is:

```
new File(bits, name[, options]);
```

My approach so far doesn't have any effects:

```
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let myFile = input[0];

var reader = new FileReader();
var fileByteArray = [];

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(myFile);
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
        var arrayBuffer = evt.target.result,
        array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            fileByteArray.push(array[i]);
        }

        var f = new File(fileByteArray, "myNewFileName" + '.jpg', { type: revFile.type, lastModified: new Date().now() });
    }
}
```

What is it that I am missing?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could this perhaps be what you are looking for:

```
var input = document.querySelector("input[id=file-input]");
let myFile = input.files[0];

var copiedFile = new File([myFile], "myNewFileName" + ".jpg", {
  type: "image/jpeg",
  lastModified: new Date(),
});
```

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/kristofvdj88/pen/xxZRRXL?editors=1111